# Different moving sprites not showing in pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm making a small game in Python using pygame, I'm trying to make my character move in different directions on the screen in response to the user pressing direction arrows on the keyboard. Each direction the character moves into has 3 sprites that should be displayed consecutively. The problem is, even though the character does move up & down according to me pressing the keyboard arrows up & down. Only The sprites for the up arrow works, if I try to move the character down it does move but it stays on the previous sprite state it had when I moved it up (i.e. no down sprites are shown at all). This is strange since the code for both up & down sprites is exactly the same & yet only one of them works on top of the other! I have included the parts of the code which I think are relevant, any help would be much appreciated.

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,70))
finished = False
x = 450 - 35/2
y = 650   #initial co-ordiantes of the player

backSprites = ["data/hero/walk-back1.png", "data/hero/walk-back2.png", "data/hero/stand-back.png"]
back_index = 0
backSpritesModified1 = [pygame.image.load(filename) for filename in backSprites]
backSpritesModified2 = [pygame.transform.scale((filename), (45, 50) for filename in backSpritesModified1]
backSpritesModified3 = [(filename).convert_alpha() for filename in backSpritesModified2]
#These previous lines work perfectly when the up button is pressed

frontSprites = ["data/hero/walk-front1.png", "data/hero/walk-front2.png", "data/hero/stand-front.png"]
front_index = 0
frontSpritesModified1 = [pygame.image.load(filename) for filename in frontSprites]
frontSpritesModified2 = [pygame.transform.scale((filename), (45, 50) for filename in frontSpritesModified1]
frontSpritesModified3 = [(filename).convert_alpha() for filename in frontSpritesModified2]
#as you can see it's written in the same syntax as the previous part but doesn,t work
```

The following parts of the code is included in a while loop and like I said, it's the only relevant parts so I'm only including them

```
while finished == False #while the game isn't finished yet
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            finished = True

    pressedKeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressedKeys[pygame.K_UP] == 1:
        y -= 5
        back_index = (back_index + 1) %len(backSpritesModified3)
    if pressedKeys[pygame.K_DOWN] == 1:
        y += 5
        front_index = (front_index + 1) %len(frontSpritesModified3)
#not working even though it's the same syntax as the previous one!
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need to see at least how you blit the images/surfaces.

Comment: Ok, here is a link to the full code of the game so far. The goal is to make the player reach the top of the screen where there is a treasure and avoid being hit by zombies. feel free to put different images in the paths of the sprites

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7F-SKlHDPGlak9xQkhUTmhjUlk/view

Comment: Don't post links to your code, insert a minimal, complete and verifiable example into the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimum working example without images, but you will see text on the screen that shows you what animation is being played and which frame it is on. This should help you see how switching between animations, based on an entities state, can be done. There are many ways to do this. Also, without seeing other parts of your code, it's hard to see where things could be going wrong.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(pygame.font.get_default_font(), 25)

running = True;

anim_idle = ['idle-1']
anim_up = ['up-1', 'up-2', 'up-3']
anim_down = ['down-1', 'down-2', 'down-3']

anim_dict = {'up': anim_up, 'down': anim_down, 'idle': anim_idle}
anim_speed = 0.25# each frame of the animation lasts 1/4 of a second

current_anim_name = 'idle'
current_anim = anim_dict.get(current_anim_name)
current_anim_frame = 0
current_frame_time = 0

def change_anim(anim_name):
    global current_anim_name, current_anim, current_anim_frame, current_frame_time
    current_anim_name = anim_name
    current_anim = anim_dict.get(anim_name)
    current_anim_frame = 0
    current_frame_time = 0

while running:
    dt = clock.tick() * 0.001# delta time in seconds
    current_frame_time = current_frame_time + dt
    if current_frame_time >= anim_speed:
        current_anim_frame = (current_anim_frame + 1)%len(current_anim)
        current_frame_time = 0
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                change_anim('up')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                change_anim('down')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pass
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pass
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                change_anim('idle')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                change_anim('idle')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                pass
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                pass
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(font.render(current_anim_name + ' :: frame ' + current_anim[current_anim_frame], True, (255,255,255)), (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```